# How to copy-paste information from one drawing to another one in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net, copy-paste

In Draw.Io is there a way to copy-paste information from one drawing on one tab to another one in a different tab?

I couldn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Just to make it easier for people searching here; they did provide an option for cut and paste listed at the above link. > We've added experimental support for this using local storage. It can be enabled with the `clipboard=storage` URL parameter as follows: https://www.draw.io/?clipboard=storage

Comment: "Above" where? Please note that answers can be sorted in a number of different ways, so what might be "above" this answer for you won't be true later or for someone else. Better to link to the answer/post to which you're referring.

Comment: In David's answer about the feature request list  https://jgraph.freshdesk.com/support/discussions/forums/107935 (the last entry shows the answer)

Comment: Frankly, it would have been better to edit this information into that answer.

Comment: I'm new to the stackexchange world..

Comment: No worries. We all were, once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select all, copy on origin ( using keyboard ), paste using keyboard into targer. If it doesn't work, bugs go to https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues

Comment: what does this link do? I already have two tabs open. Will I be able to copy selected diagram from one tab to another?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this using the scratchpad feature on the left-side menu. In the 'source' diagram, I dragged the component I wanted to copy into the scratchpad, then I opened the 'target' diagram and dragged it out of the scratchpad.

Comment: Works great.  Note, you may have to turn on the scratchpad in the View menu.

Answer (score 1):

As of 11 November 2020, I have found the following solution.

**Software used:** Diagrams.net 13.7.9

**Solution Summary:** Using mouse controls to select, copy, from source drawing and paste into new drawing does not function properly. However, using keyboard controls does function correctly.

**Solution Steps:**

1. Use keyboard CONTROL A to select all item on source drawing,
2. Use keyboard CONTROL C to copy all selected items from source drawing,
3. Open target page/work area
4. Use keyboard CONTROL V to paste the copied items into their new location.

Comment: Agreed: Copy and Paste with the mouse right-click->Copy does not allow paste into another document. Nor does right-click->Paste allow paste into the other document. It must all be done with the keyboard. (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this succesfully by importing one diagram in file A to another diafram in file B. This is how I did (as March 30th 2022):

- Grouped all objects in file A and saved
- Opened file B and selected File > Import and imported file A

It came as a new layer 'Background' although I already had one with the same name.
Hope this helps.